# Azure CLI - Azure Advisor Recommendation - does not have cost data for 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'

Tags: azure

I was using az cli to get the Azure advisor recommendation data

```
az advisor recommendation list  --category cost  --subscription ************* -o json --query  "[?impactedField == 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'].{resource: impactedValue, cat: category, cpu:  extendedProperties.MaxCpuP95 , memory:  extendedProperties.MaxMemoryP95, saving:  extendedProperties.savingsAmount, Recommendation: shortDescription.solution }"
```

While downloading pdf from portal it has "Potential savings/yr" . I found az cli is retuning  different output for "Reserve Instances Recommendation" but for VM's it does not have cost related information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below PowerShell cmdlet to pull the Potential savings of the virtual machine's in the subscription.

```
Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation -Category Cost | Where-Object {$_.ImpactedField -eq "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ExtendedProperties
```